# Using \left after array to increase bracket } size

Tags: brackets

I want to use \left to increase the size of a bracket } after an array. I don't want to use commands like \Big as shown in the example. The reason why is that I will use this several times for different arrays with various lengths.

The first part of the code is my unsuccesful try.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{array}{c}
f(x)  \\  g(x)  \\   h(x)
\end{array}\left\}\right. = \ldots
\]

\[
\begin{array}{c}
f(x)  \\  g(x)  \\  h(x)
\end{array}\Bigg\} = \ldots
\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also can use one of `\big, \Big, \bigg, \Biggl/r`, or one of the  `rcases, drcases, rcases*, drcases*`  environment from `mathtools`, or the `empheq` environment from the homonymous package.

Note, you don't have to load `amsmath` in these cases,, since  empheq  loads  mathtools, which in turn loads amsmath.

Examples:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{empheq} %

\begin{document}

\[ \begin{rcases}
  f(x) \\ g(x) \\ \frac{h(x)}{k(x)} %
  \end{rcases}\qquad \begin{drcases}
  f(x) \\ g(x) \\ \frac{h(x)}{k(x)} %
  \end{drcases} \]%

  \begin{empheq}[right=\empheqrbrace\text{\footnotesize by hypothesis}]{align*}
    a  & = b + c \\
    x &  = u + v + w \\
    d &  = e + f
  \end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't know about the *rcases* and *dcases* and also about *empheq*.

Comment: You definitely should take a look at the documentations. The number of tools for fine tuning of math formulae is really impressive.

Answer (score 1):

I figured an answer myself but anyway descided to post the question since it might be useful for someone else.

When you use \left \right to adjust the size of a bracket you use . If you want to increase the size of a bracket to the left of an array you use

```
\[
\left\{\begin{array}{c}
f(x)  \\  g(x)   \\    h(x)
\end{array}\right. = \ldots
\]
```

and if you want (like in the question) to incrase the size of a bracket to the right of an array you put the . to the left:

```
\[
\left.\begin{array}{c}
f(x) \\  g(x) \\ h(x)
\end{array}\right\}
\]
```

The sad part is that sometimes \left and \right make the brackets too big.