# drcases of mathtools package

Tags: packages, mathtools

Considered my little ability in English I would like to know what is the use of `drcases` and what are the advantages or disadvantages of this command.

```
\begin{drcases} 〈math_column〉 & 〈math_column〉 \end{drcases}
\begin{drcases*} 〈math_column〉 & 〈text_column〉 \end{drcases*}
```

See the manual of `mathtools` https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/mathtools/mathtools.pdf
§ 3.4.3 More cases-like environments pag. 19.

Comment: It is a  `cases`  environment with a right brace, and  maths in `\displaystyle`.

Comment: @Bernard I have never used it and hadn't seen an example in the manual. I understand the controls if I see some examples. Thank you veryyyyyyyyyyyyy much.

Comment: In the answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/292905/change-fontsize-of-an-array-within-an-align-environment/292906#292906), you have an example. Please let me know if it's nos illuminating enough.

Comment: @Bernard With a lot of sincerity my question after that I have seen the link it is similar to a duplicate. For me it is important also to know the advantages or disadvantages of this command, if possibile. Otherwise I put close to my question. Thank youuuuuuuu.

Comment: I do think è possibile. There are cases (!) where you want a brace on the right, not on the left, e.g. when you want to denote that a series of conditions together imply some consequence. As to the `d` in drcases,  it may happen  that you want the formulæ inside the environment to be displaystyle (b.t.w. one might also want an   `mrcases` (medium-sized)  environment).  (I feel like I've written enough Latin expressions…). Do these explanations make it clearer to you? Or is it a *casus belli*? ;o)

Comment: @Bernard They are clear...but do you, put, please a MWE code :-). I remember your comment better.

Comment: I've found I had used it in my answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/330177/using-left-after-array-to-increase-bracket-size/330183#330183). I hope it will help.

Answer (score -1):

I'll give my answer in regards to the following example:

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
  $ \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left| \frac{b_{n+1}}{b_{n}} \right| 
    \begin{dcases}
    \begin{rcases}
    < \\
    = \\
    > 
    \end{rcases}
    \end{dcases}
    = 1 \Rightarrow
    \sum\limits_{n =0}^{\infty} b_n
    \begin{cases}
    \text{converges absolutely} \\
    \text{???} \\
    \text{diverges absolutely} 
    \end{cases} $
\end{document}
```

Here drcases is used to place left and right braces on the cases. When only left brace in necessary you can use cases.

Comment: Might be an idea to include an image of the result

Comment: Your example does not actually use `drcases`. Also `drcases` is *not* used to place braces on the left and right, it puts the brace on the right side only.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Please, can you put a screenshot of your code, considering the comments of very nice users @MarcelKrüger and dailef. Thank you.

Comment: @daleif Thank you very much for your comment. I understood also the code if I see the output. My best regards.